# User Blog difficulty Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, social-networking, buddypress, multisite

I have have a client that wants to create a Wordpress site with the following features.

1. Private Messaging
2. User profile
3. Friend Groups
4. The ability for a user to create one or many "journals" which are essentially a blog, which only their friends can see.

The last item is the one that I am puzzling over. It seems that it might be best to create a multisite where users can create their own blogs. But I'm not sure how I would manage who can see the blogs, or how I would display the blogs on the user's profile page.

Does anyone know any projects similar to this or have any ideas about where to start with a project like this?

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone who sees this.

Buddypress solves first three problems more or less out of the box.

I decided to customize the groups feature a bit to fit the bill for a user created journal. The user can create a group (groups are renamed 'journals' by means of the translation file for BP) and he is the only one allowed to post to it. I have updated some of the group meta fields so the user can add a bit more information about his journal, as well.